# Error while building custom Qt 4.8.3 library with CMake 2.8.11 on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, qt4, cmake, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to migrate my Qt project from QMake to CMake but I am getting some errors when trying to build my library on Windows 7 with MSVC10. My CMakeLists.txt files is as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 2.8.11 )

project( MyLibrary )
find_package(Qt4 REQUIRED)

set( CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON )
set( QT_USE_QTSCRIPT TRUE )

include( ${QT_USE_FILE} )
include_directories( ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/include ${QT_INCLUDES} )

set( MyLibrary_SOURCES
    src/connection.cpp
    src/mylibrary.cpp
    src/node.cpp
    src/socket.cpp
    include/connection.h
    include/mylibrary.h
    include/node.h
    include/socket.h
    include/MyLibrary_global.h
)

add_library(MyLibrary SHARED ${MyLibrary_SOURCES})

target_link_libraries(MyLibrary ${QT_LIBRARIES} )
```

When I run I try to build with the generated nmake Makefile I get the following errors:

```
C2491:'Connection::staticMetaObjectExtraData' : definition of dllimport static data member not allowed
C2491: 'Connection::staticMetaObject' : definition of dllimport static data member not allowed
```

I'm new to CMake so I'm not sure if I'm missing something in the CMakeLists.txt file or if there are more tricks to using it with Qt. I should mention that the files that are getting the errors are the MOC generated ones.

Edit:
So the output of

message(${QT_INCLUDES})

is as follows (formatting is for readability):

```
C:/Qt/4.8.3/include/QtDesigner
C:/Qt/4.8.3/include/QtDeclarative
C:/Qt/4.8.3/include/QtScriptTools
C:/Qt/4.8.3/include/QtDBus
C:/Qt/4.8.3/include/QtDesigner
C:/Qt/4.8.3/include/QtXml
C:/Qt/4.8.3/include/QtSql
C:/Qt/4.8.3/include/QtOpenGL
C:/Qt/4.8.3/include/QtMultimedia
C:/Qt/4.8.3/include/QtNetwork
C:/Qt/4.8.3/include/phonon
C:/Qt/4.8.3/include/QtXmlPatterns
C:/Qt/4.8.3/include/QtWebKit
C:/Qt/4.8.3/include/QtHelp
C:/Qt/4.8.3/include/QtUiTools
C:/Qt/4.8.3/include/QtTest
C:/Qt/4.8.3/include/QtScript
C:/Qt/4.8.3/include/QtSvg
C:/Qt/4.8.3/include/Qt3Support
C:/Qt/4.8.3/include/QtGui
C:/Qt/4.8.3/include/QtCore
C:/Qt/4.8.3/mkspecs/default
C:/Qt/4.8.3/include
C:/Qt/4.8.3/include/QtCore
```

I made tried not using auto-moc but I still get the same result and errors.

Answer (score 3):

Reading this: [Export QObject-based class to DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19238693/export-qobject-based-class-to-dll) I found what's wrong:

In .pro file I had the following:
    DEFINES +=APPLETTUTORIAL1_LIBRARY

Then in applet-tutorial1_global.h I have:

```
#if defined(APPLETTUTORIAL1_LIBRARY)
#  define APPLETTUTORIAL1SHARED_EXPORT Q_DECL_EXPORT
#else
#  define APPLETTUTORIAL1SHARED_EXPORT Q_DECL_IMPORT
#endif

#endif // APPLETTUTORIAL1_GLOBAL_H
```

Since I didn't have the equivalent in CMakeLists.txt the compiler goes to the

```
#  define APPLETTUTORIAL1SHARED_EXPORT Q_DECL_IMPORT
```

line rather than the expected one:

```
#  define APPLETTUTORIAL1SHARED_EXPORT Q_DECL_EXPORT
```

So my solution was to leave only this line and my shared library built well!

```
#  define APPLETTUTORIAL1SHARED_EXPORT Q_DECL_EXPORT
```

I tried the folllowing in CMakeLists.txt after reading this:http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake:ConvertFromQmake but I did it wrong I think, thus the solution above.

```
SET(DEFINES "APPLETTUTORIAL1_LIBRARY")
```

Answer (score 1):

Most of

http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-qt.7.html

applies to CMake 2.8.11 too. Use imported targets, not the Use file.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have 3 Ideas, not sure if they lead to a solution, but it could work.

First of all, what is in `${QT_INCLUDES}`? Add some `message(${QT_INCLUDES})` please and share the output.

The second Idea would be to mock manually, as the error orrurs in the mock. For this try to remove the `set( CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON )` and add:

```
set(QT_USE_QTUITOOLS true)

QT4_WRAP_UI(UI     UiFiles.ui)

QT4_WRAP_CPP(MOC3  QObjectFiles.h)

add_library(..........
                      ${UI} 
                      ${MOC3})
```

My third idea is to remove the `SHARED`, maybe this causes the error, but I am not sure on that one.

Please share what you get and I'll try to help :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to add a comment so I have to write an answer...
Same problem but Qt4.8.5 here.

Keep using CMAKE_AUTOMOC because QT4_WRAP_CPP is the old way of doing... I found this : http://plagatux.es/2012/12/qt-automoc-with-cmake/

When I used old way, I got the same linkage error you had. With AUTOMOC I get other linkage /compilation errors but think I can go further:

```
applettutorial1.cpp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) const tutorial1::AppletTutorial1::`vftable'{for `XAppletPlugin'}" (__imp_??_7AppletTutorial1@tutorial1@@6BXAppletPlugin@@@) referenced in function "public: __cdecl tutorial1::AppletTutorial1::AppletTutorial1(void)" (??0AppletTutorial1@tutorial1@@QEAA@XZ)
```

You might add this to your includes:

```
 ${QT_QTCORE_INCLUDE_DIR}
 ${QT_INCLUDE_DIR}
```

Hoping you solved and could give us feedback so this helps other people.

EDIT : in my case I solved the following errors to get a successful build:

- correctly check CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE against "Debug" string, not "DEBUG" as I read here and there. RTFM.
- build my lib as STATIC, not SHARED.

Comment: Successfully build as SHARED, see my full answer below.