# Export QObject-based class to DLL

Tags: qt, dll, qobject

I'm composing a class which derives from QObject, and I want to export this class into a DLL file so other applications can use it. But I got some mysterious problem here:

The code is shown below:

mydll.h:

```
 #ifndef MYDLL_H
 #define MYDLL_H

 #include "mydll_global.h"
 #include <QObject>
 #include <QDebug>

 class MYDLLSHARED_EXPORT MyDll : public QObject
 {
     Q_OBJECT
  public:
     explicit MyDll(QObject * parent = 0);

     void test() const;
 };

 #endif // MYDLL_H
```

mydll_global.h:

```
 #ifndef MYDLL_GLOBAL_H
 #define MYDLL_GLOBAL_H

 #include <QtCore/qglobal.h>

 #if defined(MYDLL_LIBRARY)
 #  define MYDLLSHARED_EXPORT Q_DECL_EXPORT
 #else
 #  define MYDLLSHARED_EXPORT Q_DECL_IMPORT
 #endif

 #endif // MYDLL_GLOBAL_H
```

mydll.cpp:

```
 #include "mydll.h"

 MyDll::MyDll(QObject * parent) :
     QObject(parent)
 {
 }

 void MyDll::test() const {
     qDebug() << "Hello from dll!";
 }
```

and the dll is used in another application. The dll is compiled successfully. I've add `LIBS += "myDll.dll"` in the `.pro` file of the application using this dll, and I've copied `myDll.dll` to the working directory of the application.

The compiler reports:

```
 C4273: "MyDll::qt_static_metacall" : inconsistent dll linkage.
 C2491: "MyDll::staticMetaObject": definition of dllimport static data member not allowed
```

What's the problem here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ definition of dllimport static data member](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3491990/c-definition-of-dllimport-static-data-member)

Answer (score 3):

Your code for `mydll_global.h` checks whether `MYDLL_LIBRARY` is defined, but none of the code you have posted defines `MYDLL_LIBRARY`.  Is this declared in a file that you have not shared on the question?  If not, you need to add a `#define MYDLL_LIBRARY` in your build project, or your PCH.

Comment: You mean adding `#define MYDLL_LIBRARY` in the project creating this dll, or the project using this dll?

Comment: The project creating this dll. The `#define MYDLL_LIBRARY` effectively lets the compiler inside the `#ifdef` block to the `Q_DECL_EXPORT` line, which tells it to export the symbols marked with the `MYDLLSHARED_EXPORT` macro (which at my company is typically marked a `MYDLLSHARED_API` since it can be export OR import). Not defining `MYDLL_LIBRARY` makes the compiler hit the `Q_DECL_IMPORT` line, which tells it to attempt to import those symbols, leading to the inconsistent DLL linkage error.  Hope that helps!